# windows phone 8 emulator and Visual studio 2012 issues

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I recently installed Windows 8 on my machine (i3 processor), also **enabled the BIOS setting** for virtualization during windows 8 installation.
Created sample app on Visual express trial version, and tried debugging.
The emulator starts and keeps shows connecting to emulator .. after 5 mins I get the error message (**The Windows Phone Emulator was not able to connect to the Windows Phone Operating Syste.
The Phone did not respond to the connect request
Some functionality might be diabled**)
I have **hyperV installed, running** and also UAC is set to Always Ask.
Also tried **deleting the virtual switch and creating a new one**, but same error
Could someone help me, seems the visual studio is not able to connect to the emulator and it times out, but I saw the **emulator switch gets an IP address** as well, where am i going wrong.

Any help is higly appreciated.
Viral

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution, the antivirus was creating its own firewall and blocking access to emulator.
Disabling windows firewall also did not help as the antivirus overrided the windows firewall.
Antivirus was Schemantic
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: i am facing same prolem, can you please explore your answer. May be it could help me.